# Logrotate.d odd behaviour

Tags: linux, logs, logrotate

I have an issue with log rotation. I'm using rsyslog to collect fairly large amounts of syslog data from some Cisco kit.

The standard syslog files are rotating/cleaning up just fine, however the ones I've added are not. Here's my config file:

```
    user@server:/var/log/remote$ cat /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
/var/log/syslog
{
        rotate 7
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
                reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        endscript
}

/var/log/mail.info
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/lpr.log
/var/log/cron.log
/var/log/debug
/var/log/messages
{
        rotate 4
        weekly
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        endscript
}

/var/log/remote/*
{
        rotate 10
        hourly
        missingok
        compress
        delaycompress
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        endscript
}
```

After a couple of days, the directory containing the syslog files looks like so:

```
user@server:/var/log/remote$ ls -l
total 312464
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  72943939 Feb 16 12:16 10.108.0.17.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm         0 Feb 16 07:47 10.108.0.17.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm         0 Feb 16 07:47 10.108.0.17.log.1.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 183577555 Feb 16 07:47 10.108.0.17.log.1.1.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   2782878 Feb 15 07:47 10.108.0.17.log.1.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   3180854 Feb 14 08:00 10.108.0.17.log.1.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm         0 Feb 16 07:47 10.108.0.17.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm        20 Feb 15 07:47 10.108.0.17.log.2.gz.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm        33 Feb 14 08:00 10.108.0.17.log.2.gz.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm         0 Feb 16 07:47 10.108.0.17.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm         0 Feb 15 07:47 10.108.0.17.log.3.gz.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  15588585 Feb 13 07:40 10.108.0.17.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   5950012 Feb 12 07:53 10.108.0.17.log.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   7012651 Feb 16 12:16 als-gwy04.mmu.ac.uk.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm         0 Feb 16 07:47 als-gwy04.mmu.ac.uk.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm         0 Feb 16 07:47 als-gwy04.mmu.ac.uk.log.1.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  26187423 Feb 16 07:47 als-gwy04.mmu.ac.uk.log.1.1.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm        20 Feb 14 08:00 als-gwy04.mmu.ac.uk.log.1.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm        20 Feb 13 07:40 als-gwy04.mmu.ac.uk.log.1.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm         0 Feb 16 07:47 als-gwy04.mmu.ac.uk.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm        20 Feb 15 07:47 als-gwy04.mmu.ac.uk.log.2.gz.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm        33 Feb 14 08:00 als-gwy04.mmu.ac.uk.log.2.gz.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm         0 Feb 16 07:47 als-gwy04.mmu.ac.uk.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm         0 Feb 15 07:47 als-gwy04.mmu.ac.uk.log.3.gz.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm    591717 Feb 12 12:36 als-gwy04.mmu.ac.uk.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   2088688 Feb 12 07:53 als-gwy04.mmu.ac.uk.log.5.gz
user@server:/var/log/remote$
```

Any ideas why they are duplicating and getting multiple suffixes rather than cleaning up like this?

```
user@server:/var/log$ ls -l sys*
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   624 Feb 16 12:17 syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  3142 Feb 16 07:47 syslog.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   530 Feb 15 07:47 syslog.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   546 Feb 14 08:00 syslog.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 47042 Feb 13 07:40 syslog.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 24152 Feb 12 07:53 syslog.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   546 Feb 11 07:43 syslog.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   534 Feb 10 07:38 syslog.7.gz
user@server:/var/log$ ^C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/var/log/remote/*` in the last rule matches all files, including *gz made from the other rules.

You should make a better regexp, for instance `10*.log` or match specific files.

As in:

```
/var/log/remote/10*.log
{
    rotate 10
    hourly
    missingok
    compress
    delaycompress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
            reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
}
```